# sys.path.insert doesn't work from terminal

Tags: python, sys.path

I wrote one python script that makes use of some libraries I contained in a different folder. To access them what I've done is adding at the beginning of the script the following lines:

```
import sys  
sys.path.insert(1, 'library_dir')
```

This is working fine when I'm using my python IDE but when I run the code from the terminal it fails in importing the libraries I'm interested in.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: go to the folder that contains libary_dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relative path problem.

The path you are inserting into `sys.path` is relative to the location that your run the script from.  Your IDE will run it from a certain directory (probably the directory of the "project" in that IDE).  If you run it from that same directory on the command line, it should work.

Alternatively, you can specify an absolute path:

Windows:

```
sys.path.insert(1, 'c:\\path\\to\\library_dir')
```

*nix:

```
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/library_dir')
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable "PYTHONPATH" before calling the python script. In bash that can be done with:

> $ export PYTHONPATH="/some/default/path:${HOME}/library_dir"